# Benchmarking a DB

Tags: database, nosql, benchmarking

I am studying the results of a benchmark (YCSB) as seen [here](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol7/p1219-klems.pdf) on a noSQL database. In my project I initially have 1.3 million users who daily insert 30MB of data each of them, collected by sensors installed on their vehicles (usage-based insurance).

The throughput resulting from the YCSB benchmark is 50000 ops / sec. Each write operation writes 1KB of data.

My system should ideally be able to read all this data at the end of the day in order to analyze it, evaluate the risk of the driver, and establish a price for the user for the next day.

The problem is that in total they write 39 TB (1,3 million * 30MB), and with this reading throughput the system takes many days (188), but I would need it in 1 hour.

The question is: if a write op is 1KB, is read 1KB or can it be faster in a schema-less database?

Does the read throughput means something different? I can not believe there results.

Thanks.

Comment: Is each user independent?  If so, you don't need them all in the same database, so you can parallelize with multiple servers, each one handling some of your users.  Then your analysis can also run in parallel.  I'd assume that a big read of all the data could be faster than individual writes, but IDK if we have enough info to say.  It would depend on the hardware and the details.

Comment: I want to show my system is scalable. I have 4 master nodes that collects information about each users (1 million) in a schema-less JSON format, so can I suppose that a read operation retrieves more than 1KB/ops read? My goal is to show that with 8 nodes I can read and analyze data about 10 million users, as I did for the write operation. Also, each master node has 2 replica set, so when they are updated I can increase parallelism. I do not know how to prove it with math using these benchmark's results.